# Can I use powerline without patched fonts?

Tags: powerline, vim-powerline

As part of work, I frequently remote login to my workstation from a different laptop every week or so. Powerline works perfectly with the patched fonts on the workstation itself, but it looks and works horrible if I don't have the patched fonts. The cursor is 2 characters to the left of the end of line and messes up my commands.

It's not really practical for me to keep installing fonts on every new machine that I login from. Is there a way to have powerline work without the fancy patched fonts and glyphs? I'd be happy if it just uses stock characters in a font like 'inconsolata' so that I can login remotely in peace.